# Expression expected for return function when rendering a component

Tags: reactjs

I am writing a simple component and keep receiving `expression expected` after the first parenthesis of the return function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class EventsPage extends Component{
    render(){
        return( //<- error underlined here

        );
    }
}
```

Edit:

[image]

Edit 2:

[image]

Comment: you need to return a jsx, something like <div></div>

Comment: It did not change the error (if I understand you correctly you meant that I need to have div tags inside)

Comment: Can you please reproduce what you have done so far in this [react sandbox](https://codepen.io/pen?template=vvRRNg)?

Comment: It requires sign-up, I wrote in exactly the code added above and didn't receive the error. I added a picture

Comment: You need *something* inside the parenthesis.

Comment: I added jsx but still the same, I added another picture.

Comment: Syntax looks good to me. Try other IDE?

Comment: I think these are just ESLint `prettier` errors/suggestions, to change indentation and such. either disable ESLint from your IDE settings, or apply the suggested changes

Comment: your code is correct, you must check your react package it must be installed and as wasim said it might be one of the issue.

Comment: I am using WebStorm. I don't think it has something to do with formatting, when it is underlined in red it means a coding error. Package `react` was installed with `npm`

Comment: If it helps: I am using nodejs and express

Comment: What message do you get now after you added the `<div>hi</div>` when you hover the mouse over the error?

Comment: I've deleted it. It might be because I was using WebStorm for a NodeJS+Express application, but I'm really not sure...